# RestSharp matching Curl syntax

Tags: c#, rest, get, restsharp

I'm trying to talk to an API, which seems to be using a non-standard setup, here's the curl request that works:

```
curl -d '{"id" : "blah"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://127.0.0.1:2796/api/0.8/testing/testme
```

This returns what I expect, however whenever I try to do this using RestSharp, the API returns an error stating that it received no json.  Here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
var client = new RestClient(server);
var request = new RestRequest("/api/0.8/testing/testme", Method.GET);

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddJsonBody(new {id = "blah"});

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.
Console.WriteLine("Response: " + content);
```

It's a GET request, but it needs to also send json data, so I'm bit confused as to how that works.  Does it put it in the body, or in the URL?

Any advice or input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you posting JSON in a get request?  That doesn't make sense.

Are you sure you don't mean that you are posting JSON and then receiving a JSON response?

My suggestion is to download a tool called "Postman" and try to get it working there first.

Try this:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:2796/api/0.8/testing/testme");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"id\" : \"blah\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Then you can read the response and interpret that into your project.

Using

```
request.AddParameter("","",ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

instead of

```
AddJsonBody
```

Comment: Nope, the API is setup to require a body in a GET request, I know it's strange, but it's not against the HTTP spec, it's not not standard.  Some other API's from the likes of Google also do this.